# How to use "{" character in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I know we use {{ }} characters for variables but I want to show my datas between {} characters

I want to show November{12}  like that. So what I did is:

```
<ul>
    {% for month in archive %}
<li><a href="?{{month.date|date:"Y-m"}}">{{month.date|date:"F Y"}}{{{month.count}}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But I got an error like that:

Could not parse the remainder: '{month.count' from '{month.count'

How to use { character in template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul>
    {% for month in archive %}
<li><a href="?{{month.date|date:"Y-m"}}">{{month.date|date:"F Y"}}&#123;{{month.count}}&#125;</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: is ``month.count`` understood by the template in this case ? i thought, only in {{ }} django can interprete the variable..

Answer (score -1):

render the `{` and `}` as `b_s` and `b_e` to your template and do this:

```
<ul>
{% for month in archive %}
<li><a href="?{{month.date|date:"Y-m"}}">{{month.date|date:"F Y"}} {{b_s}} {{month.count}}      {{b_e}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```